# Why did a directory changed its own size after loading from one server to another?

Tags: disk-usage, file-transfer

Our administrator said us to backup our data from one cluster to another because the first has a chance to fall out in the near future.

I encountered a very strange phenomenon with *anaconda3* directory (this is not necessary data but I am very interested to figure it out). It weighs *9.4 G* before transferring & *20 G* after it (I checked through `du -sh`).

I use **sftp** as `sftp -Cpr -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=5 -P [*****] user@host.domain` & a command **get** `get -pr ~/anaconda3 ~/backup/`.

Why are the sizes so different?

Comment: Lots of hard links, perhaps? Do you get different outputs with `du -lsh`?

Comment: This could be down to the difference in filesystems. E.g directories with thousands of files on ext4 take a lot more space than on XFS.

Comment: @muru I got equal sizes & acquainted with a hard link term. Is there a way to copy a directory through **sftp** preserving hard links as they are. Or should I use another tool?

Comment: I did not find anything useful in **sftp** manual.

Comment: @Vovin `rsync` has a `--hard-links`/`-H` option

Comment: Is it possible that one or more files is `sparse` ? `find` has a `%S` print option to report sparseness, but you cannot select files based on sparseness.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I thought about this but not, *muru* is right, this turned out because of copying hard links as whole files by **sftp**.